# How to DRY up RSpec tests shared by different actions in same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following tests that I want tested from various actions in the same controller. How can I DRY this up? In the comments below you'll see that the test should call a different method and action depending on which action I'm testing.

```
shared_examples_for "preparing for edit partial" do

  it "creates a new staff vacation" do
    StaffVacation.should_receive(:new)
    get :new
  end

  it "assigns @first_day_of_week" do
    get :new
    assigns(:first_day_of_week).should == 1
  end

end


describe "GET new" do
  # i want to use 'it_behaves_like "preparing for edit partial"'
  # and it should use 'get :new'
end

describe "GET edit" do
  # i want to use 'it_behaves_like "preparing for edit partial"'
  # but it should use 'get :edit' instead
end

describe "POST create" do
  # on unsuccessful save, i want to use 'it_behaves_like "preparing for edit partial"'
  # but it should use 'post :create' instead
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
shared_examples_for "preparing for edit partial" do
  let(:action){ get :new }

  it "creates a new staff vacation" do
    StaffVacation.should_receive(:new)
    action
  end

  it "assigns @first_day_of_week" do
    action
    assigns(:first_day_of_week).should == 1
  end
end

context 'GET new' do
  it_should_behave_like 'preparing for edit partial' do
    let(:action){ get :new }
  end
end

context 'GET edit' do
  it_should_behave_like 'preparing for edit partial' do
    let(:action){ get :edit }
  end
end

context 'POST create' do
  it_should_behave_like 'preparing for edit partial' do
    let(:action){ post :create }
  end
end
```

Or, you could use some kind of loop for the examples:

```
['get :new', 'get :edit', 'post :create'].each do |action|
  context action do
    it "creates a new staff vacation" do
      StaffVacation.should_receive(:new)
      eval(action)
    end

    it "assigns @first_day_of_week" do
      eval(action)
      assigns(:first_day_of_week).should == 1
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to provide a module mix-in with a method that has your spec inside it.

```
include Auth # This is your module with your generalized spec inside a method

it "redirects without authentication" do
  unauthorized_redirect("get", "new")
end
```

Then, in our method, we could do a loop through different types of authorization:

```
module Auth
  def unauthorized_redirect(request, action)
    [nil, :viewer, :editor].each do |a| 
      with_user(a) do
        eval "#{request} :#{action}"
        response.should redirect_to login_path
        # whatever other expectations
      end
    end 
  end
end
```